# How to know if current shell is from a docker OS or system main OS?

Tags: 16.04, docker

I have ssh into an remote shell. How can I make sure that the OS which I am working on is not a docker container?

PS: I wanted to know some way that tells me whether a shell is from docker OS or not. Some kind of command in ubuntu (Unix) or some file system that are different than system OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can examine the mounted filesystems:

```
# findmnt /
TARGET SOURCE  FSTYPE  OPTIONS
/      overlay overlay rw,relatime,lowerdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/2BKZYT7DSBOB576UNDXZTPXFKY:...
```

In this case the root filesystem is from a Docker overlay mount, making it highly likely it's a Docker container.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to look at the application bar and see what machine you're connected to. Alternatively you could change the `ps1` value of your Bash prompt to clearly state what it is. By default it will be something like `{user}@{hostname}`, but it doesn't have to be like this.

Assuming the Docker container is Ubuntu-based, you may be able to edit the `~/.bashrc` file and add this to the bottom:

```
PS1="Docker> "
```

Then refresh Bash with `source ~/.bashrc` to see the change. Your prompt should now look like:

```
Docker>
```

Hope this gives you an option to consider.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I wanted to know some way that tells me whether a shell is from docker OS or not. Some kind of command in ubuntu (Unix) or some file system that are different than system OS

Answer (score 1):

Just run this command (inside ssh, local or docker) :

`hostmane`

Also, you can check the **ip** adress of host via:

`hostname -i`

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hostname.1.html